# when using SoapUI, is there a way to show multiple Requests on the same page?

Tags: layout, soapui

I am using SoapUI 5.6.0. I find the multiple opened request windows are very annoying,

1. all of them have the same label name "Request 1"
2. if you run another request, the previous one will be covered and find to find it out again.

[image]
do u have any tips to improve this usability? For example, show all the requests on one page? like showing multiple files in Notepad++?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 workaround that you can use

**First way**

1. Click on **minimise** button on top right corner of a request
2. Notice there at the down you will see like notepad++
3. you are free to move those tabs of multiple request to anywhere on the screen..

Like below you can see 1 is **below** and few are at the **top**

[image]

So every time you minimise one you can see others tabs..

**you can adjust window size so you can see all at the same time. after maximising**

**Second way**

Another better alternative is to use **ctrl+w**

[image]

Comment: Many thanks ! Personally I think solution 2 is more handy, and it could be better if we could change the tile of each command window, like, change 'Request 1' to the name of the Soap call. Do you know how to change the window title?

Comment: @ulyssis2 can you pleas accept this as an answer ? You can easily rename it from the left side explorer bar by renaming your original request from request1 to something understandable by right click or F2 from the navigator on the left side

Comment: thanks. I can rename the request in the explorer bar, but it takes a lot of effort, when the requests are many. Do you know how to automate the naming of each request, like, changing the wsdl file?

Comment: Yeah just open the saved xml file of your project and do the change in notepad... Next time when you open you will find the name changed.. But do it carefully

Comment: using that XML file with any language you can automate all the existing request name, but do a dry run to check if it selected the correct request names